# How can I improve Cloud Vision for PDF/Tiff Performance?

Tags: python-3.x, latency, google-cloud-vision

I am using Python to make a request to the Cloud Vision API for PDF documents.  During initial testing, I've seen a latency of ~15 seconds.  That's not including the overhead time it takes to create the file on Google Storage.  Has anyone achieved better performance than that?

Comment: Hi Melissa, which method are you using? AsyncBatchAnnotateFiles ?https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.vision.v1#google.cloud.vision.v1.ImageAnnotator.AsyncBatchAnnotateFiles

How many pages are there in your pdf?

Comment: @Brendan I am using AsyncBatchAnnotateFiles. I'm processing resumes, so the PDFs should be 1-3 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is now offering [online small batch processing](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/document-small-batch). I've seen much better latency. It only works for documents up to 5 pages, but that works for my use case.